# The simplest way to find a parametrization of the plane projective curve $XZ-Y^2=0$.

Tags: algebraic-curves, projective-geometry

I have to explain to some first year math students that the projective algebraic set $\textbf{Z}(XZ-Y^2)\subset\mathbb P^2_k$ is 
$$V=\{(a^2_0:a_0a_1:a^2_1)\subset\mathbb P^2_k \,:\, \textrm{for}\; a_0,a_1\in k\}$$

It is evident that $V\subseteq \textbf{Z}(XZ-Y^2)$, but which is, in your opinion, the simplest way to show the other inclusion?

Comment: Do you have any condition on $k$? I don't think that this representation is possible over an arbitrary field. For example, consider $k = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$. Then the point $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ is a zero of $XZ-Y^2$, but there is no $x \in k$ such that $x^2 = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: $k$ is algebraically closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $(x:y:z) \in \mathbf{Z}(XZ - Y^2)$. Then we know that $xz - y^2 = 0$, i.e.
$$
y^2 = xz
$$
Since $k$ is algebraically closed by hypothesis $\sqrt{x},\sqrt{z} \in k$, thus
$$
(x:y:z) = (x : \sqrt{x} \sqrt{z} : z) \in V
$$
so $\mathbf{Z}(XZ - Y^2) \subseteq V$ and we're done.

Comment: Note, by $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{z}$ I only mean a choice of square roots for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, lots of number theory of quadratic forms happens because all null vectors of your form, with rational integer entries, are integer multiples of
$$ \left( u^2 , u v, v^2  \right) $$
with $\gcd(u,v)=1.$

I'm just sayin'